# Trying to create mongoDB collection using below two mongoDB collection based on ID using python

Tags: python, mongodb

Trying to create mongoDB collection using below two mongoDB collection based on ID using python

**Mongo Collecton ABC:**

```
{
    Id : 1
    ABC_Action : 234
    Name: "Naveen"
    Age : 30
}
```

**MongoDB collection DEF:**

```
{
    Id : 1
    Action : 456
    Name: "Manish"
    Age : 33
}
```

Compare MongoDB collection ABC and DEF based on Id and If matches, get ABC_Action from ABC and other key value pairs from DEF.

**Result:**

```
{
    ABC_Action : 234
    Name : "Manish"
    Age : 33
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `$lookup` in an aggregate to join two collections.

- `$lookup` is doing a join on both `_id` fields
- `$addFields` is used to take the first element of `def_objects because` $lookup` only return an array
- `$project` to take the fields you want from either ABC or EDF collections

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "DEF",
      let: {
        "abc_id": "$_id",
        
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$abc_id",
                "$_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "def_objects"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "def_objects": {
        "$first": "$def_objects"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "ABC_Action": "$ABC_Action",
      "Name": "$def_objects.Name",
      "Age": "$def_objects.Age"
    }
  }
]
```

try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q1XN376PS6C)

If you want to save the result in an other collection, you can use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator